# Stop NOW() Function from Auto Updating

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell which I want to record the time when adjacent cells to the left are changed. I do it with the NOW() function; however, the problem is that the time gets updated each time workbook is re-calculated. So, I am wondering whether there is any original way to prevent this very cell from auto-updating.

My current formula in the cell:

=IF(ISBLANK(H11),"",IF(H11="Interested",NOW(),IF(H11="Not Interested",NOW(),"")))

I personally have come up with this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Destination As Range
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
      Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
   End If
End Sub
```

My issue with this code is that it is looking for any data in the cell. I am only wanting the cell to record the time when it contains either "Interested" or "Not Interested". The cell that I am looking at currently contains "In-progress". I have tried playing around with my code to try and incorporate these criteria's but I keep getting hit with errors.  Any advice on what I can do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check by using `If StrComp(.Cells(1,1),"Interested")=0 Then`

Comment: `if target.value like "*interested" and target.offset(0,1).value="" then .....` read your formula and code off that, your formula should us an error trap of SEARCH function, to be in line with the code suggestions. `IF(ISERR(SEARCH("interested",H11)),"",NOW())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Destination As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
        If LCase(Trim(Target.Value2)) = "not interested" Or LCase(Trim(Target.Value)) = "interested" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Ralph. Unfortunately nothing is showing up when I try your code. I change the cell to contain Interested but no time is shown in the adjacent cell.

Comment: using `option compare text` would eliminate the need for the lcase.

Comment: The code works fine (as you can see in the updated solution with a screen-cast. So, you might want to check if events are currently enabled on your sheet or if there is a spelling mistake when you enter `interested`.

Comment: My apologies Ralph, I had made a typo. Code works perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: I have now come across a new error. I have a module created to move data once certain criteria has been met. When I run this module I'm now presented with the error "Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch". This has me baffled as my module worked perfectly before inputting the new code.

Comment: Let me guess. That happened when you selected several cells and pressed the `Del` button. Anyway, this error occurs when you are updating more than one cell at a time. That's because the above code is designed for an update to one cell at a time (just like your original code). If you want the code to work for several updates at once then the code gets even more complex. But that's a new question and has nothing to do with the fact that the above solution works and solved the posted problem.

Comment: You could use `If LCase(Target.Value2) Like "*not interested*"`

Comment: If it's just this worksheet change you want to address you can add the following to the start of the function so multiple updated cells aren't processed: If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

Comment: Flephal - thank you so much. That one line of code solved my error.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is a simple UDF that you use as =TimeChanged(H11)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Function TimeChanged(theCell As Variant)
    If TypeOf theCell Is Range Then theCell = theCell.Value2
    If theCell = "Interested" Or theCell = "Not Interested" Then
        TimeChanged = Now
    Else
        TimeChanged = ""
    End If
End Function
```